# Group a column of a data frame based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

Based on this dataframe

```
  df1  Name     Age
       Johny     15
       Diana     35
       Doris     97
       Peter     25
       Antony    55
```

I have this dataframe with the number of ranges that I want to use, for example

```
 df2 Header   Init1   Final1   Init2  Final2  Init3  Final3
     Names    NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
     Age       0        20      21      50      51    100
```

What I'm looking for is to get a result like this

```
  df3  Name     Age
       Johny    0-20
       Diana    21-50
       Doris    51-100
       Peter    21-50
       Antony   51-100
```

I don't know if a possible solution is with *cut ()* but I'm new to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
l = df2.iloc[1,1:].tolist()
labels = [str(t[0])+'-'+str(t[1]) for t in zip(l[::1],l[1::1])]

df['Age'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=l, labels=labels)

print(df)
     Name     Age
0   Johny    0-20
1   Diana   21-50
2   Doris  51-100
3   Peter   21-50
4  Antony  51-100
```

Comment: The result is fine but what I don't want is to write the values that are in 1, what I want is that you read them from the other dataframe.

Comment: Is there any way you read the name of the column and not your position? because I want to apply it in a dataframe with more data and there aren't longer the same positions

Comment: @IriSandivel Yes, using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: Could you give me an example? I apologize for the inconvenience but I'm still a novice

Comment: @IriSandivel Check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: it returns this error:   the label [Init1] is not in the [index]'

Comment: @IriSandivel You need to use `['Init1']`.

Comment: @IriSandivel You need to read the [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) documentation and in this `df.loc[ Here use the index, Here use the column name]` if the columns are more than one use list of column names.